# Are bus tickets valid proof of internal transit within the Schengen territory?

Tags: schengen, tickets, schengen-visas, buses, flixbus

I will be applying for a short term tourist schengen visa at VFS Italy from Bangalore, India.

According to their '[documents required](http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/mumbai/pdf/Tourist-Visa-Application-Arrangement.pdf)' section, it's mentioned

> Proof of all internal travel within the Schengen territory including
>   train bookings, car rentals

I would like to know if bus tickets booked via. [Flixbus](https://global.flixbus.com/) are valid proof of transit within the Schengen territory (within and across countries) or not?

Answer (score 3):

They have to be, since they're all you'll have if you're traveling by bus.  A bus ticket isn't appreciably different from a train ticket in this regard.

To look at it another way, if bus tickets were invalid as proof of internal travel, that would be tantamount to a rule that people using Schengen visas are not allowed to travel from one Schengen country to another by bus.  Such a rule makes no sense, and would surely be opposed by bus operators.  There has been no such controversy, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Since I will be travelling on a budget. Busses seem to be the cheapest option. I was worried because they didn't mention anything about bus tickets in their "documents required" section.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog the word "including" means that the following list is not exhaustive, but rather a list of examples.  Other similar evidence is also acceptable.  A series of hostel bookings within 40 km of each other would similarly suffice as evidence that you're going to be walking everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

At [Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en) (I work there) we're aware of people using our tickets for visa purposes (e.g. as proof of onward travel) all around the world. I've never heard of them being rejected.

Of course immigration agents have a lot of discretion in most places but they indeed seem to treat bus tickets equally to tickets from any other mode of transportation.